# Sizing Form with Mouse works, with code doesn't go below 178x47

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, size

This

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Size = new System.Drawing.Size(8, 8);
    Console.WriteLine("Size: " + Size);
}
```

produces this as the output:

> Size: {Width=178, Height=47}

Now I guess that is because some space is needed for the title bar and its controls and the form border.

But after removing all these things the result still is the same, **even though I can reduce the Form to anything smaller when using the Mouse!**

Here is the tiny program I tried to improve with a keyboard interface:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(6, 6);
    }

    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
        }
    } 

    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = Width + " x " + Height + " px";
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right && e.Shift) Width++;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down && e.Shift) Height++;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left && e.Shift) Width--;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up && e.Shift) Height--;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) Left++;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) Top++;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) Left--;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) Top--;
    }
}
```

The Form has one Label and nothing else:

```
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(282, 253);
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(2, 2);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.ShowIcon = false;
        this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
        this.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseDown);
        this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Resize);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();
```

I wonder why the mouse lets me shrink it but the code doesn't?
Are there some style bits I need to set?

Comment: Form.SetBoundsCore() gets in the way, called when you set the size yourself instead of letting Windows determine the size as is done by the modal sizing loop.  it uses SystemInformation.MinWindowTrackSize and that's too large for a borderless window.  You can override it.

Comment: Hm that starts to make some sense. Did you mean override SetBoundsCore? Or MinWindowTrackSize ? (I'm not really at home at these depths of windforms/-dows internales..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because of the forms border style, looks like changing it to None allows the form to shrink smaller. Also moving the re-sizing code to the form's load event helps.

Edit:
Setting `FormBorderStyle to SizeableToolWindow` seems like the best fit, allows the form to be pretty small and still resized using the mouse.

Comment: With Border=None I can't resize the Form with either the keyboard events not the  muse. It allows smaller sizes, though, but I need to use the program interactively!

Comment: I've been able to resize the form using the keyboard when the border is set to None. Obviously you can't use the mouse though, as you said. How small do you want it to be able to go?

Comment: You are right about the keyboard, (I had a test button in the way stealing keyboard focus ;-) - I didn't want to set a limit; maybe I can combine the two and turn off the border when things get too small. But for larger sizes the mouse is necessary..

Comment: Easily done :). Border style SizeableToolWindow looks to allow it to be pretty small, and allow mouse resizing.

Comment: YES! SizeableToolWindow does the job perfectly. Do add it to the answer! And delete the part about moving the resizing code - it is necessary to always display the current size..!

Comment: Added the additional info. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `CreateParams` for `Form` and setting `WS_POPUP` style allows to set any size for `Form` in case `FormBorderStyle` is set to `FormBorderStyle.None`. Otherwise, size of the border and title will be added.

```
uint WS_POPUP = 0x80000000;

protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
        createParams.Style |= unchecked((int)WS_POPUP);
        return createParams;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: @TaW it allows to change Window size to any you want. Or it is not that you asked?

Comment: Yes it is but adding this to the code just didn't make any difference.

Comment: Then maybe I understand you wrong, but after I added this code and set `FormBorderStyle` to 'FormBorderStyle.None' I am able to set any size for my `Form` via property `Size` from code.

Comment: Yes with BorderStyle None setting the Size in code does work; but now the mouse doesn't work.. The solution is simply using the SizeableToolWindow borderstyle.

Comment: Now I see. I was thinking that Border and possibility of resizing by mouse it is not important for you.